# How can I get product count in each category like WooCommerce back-end?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am building a new site and I am pretty comfortable with Woocommerce. I just need a quick trick to get the product count in each category. I'm already calling out the category on each product but cannot figure out how to get the product count from that category.

I have a list style going for my products(really activities for an activity site). [Check out image](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/13502930/mac.png).

I just want to echo out the count of "activities" next to the category. This is how I am getting my category:

```
echo $product->get_categories( ', ', '<span class="posted_in">' . _n( 'Category:', 'Categories:', sizeof( get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'product_cat' ) ), 'woocommerce' ) . ' ', '.</span>' );
```

I tried to get the count by using:

```
$numposts = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_status = 'publish'");
echo $numposts;
```

But it is echoing out some weird number. I tried a few variations of that query, calling out for product and such.

**[update]**

This is what I was able to do:

```
<li><?php 
$cat1 = $product->get_categories( ', ', '<span class="posted_in">' . _n(     'Category:', 'Categories:', sizeof( get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'product_cat' ) ),  'woocommerce' ) . ' ', '.</span>' ); 
echo $cat1;
/* 
$args = array( 'taxonomy' =>  'product_cat' ); 
$terms = get_terms('product_cat', $args); 
echo count($terms);
*/ 
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'product',  'taxonomy' => $cat1[0] ); 
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); 
    echo count( $loop->post->ID ) 
endwhile; 
wp_reset_query(); // Remember to reset 
?></li>
```

But it actually counts out all the products in all categories by increments of "1".... So instead of echoing "category: abc has "3" product" it's echoing "category: abc has "1 1 1 1 1 1 1"

I know there is a simple filter that I can do here, I feel like I am right there.

Comment: Observations: 1) **Only use** open `<?php` and close `?>` tags  to separate PHP from HTML. It is not a line break. 2) Organize your code, so you don't go mad. It's *much* easier to debug and read. See [coding standards](http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Coding_Standards). 3) Use [`var_dump`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php) and [`print_r`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php) to inspect your variables.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok So thanks for putting me on the right track brasofilo, I am sure that I have some redundancy going on, but this gets me what I need.

```
<?php $cat1 = $product->get_categories( ', ', '<span class="posted_in">' . _n(       'Category:', 'Categories:', sizeof( get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'product_cat' ) ), 'woocommerce' ) . ' ', '</span>' ); 

//get the category ID and permalink
$term_list = wp_get_post_terms($post->ID,'product_cat',array('fields'=>'ids'));
$cat_id = (int)$term_list[0];
$term = get_term( $cat_id, 'product_cat' ); 

//echo the category, product count, and link
echo  $cat1 . '<a href='. get_term_link ($cat_id, 'product_cat') .'>' . ' See all ' .   $term->count . ' Activities</a>';


?>
```

Answer (score 12):

Both functions [**`get_term`**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_term) and [**`get_terms`**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_terms) will return objects that already contain the category count.

If you want to *retrieve all* WooCommerce product categories and print their post count:

```php
$terms = get_terms( 'product_cat' );
// DEBUG
// var_dump( $terms ); 
foreach( $terms as $term ) 
{
    echo 'Product Category: '
        . $term->name
        . ' - Count: '
        . $term->count;
}
```

If you want to check *only one* category that you previously know the ID:

```
$term = get_term( 16, 'product_cat' ); // <--- tested in my system with this ID
echo 'Product Category: '
    . $term->name
    . ' - Count: '
    . $term->count;
```