# How to I can display products count after each categories title in the woocmmerce shop page?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, product, categories, hook-woocommerce

[Please check the captured image. I want to display the products count number after each categories title](https://i.stack.imgur.com/08qbb.png)

Answer (score 0):

not all theme comes with this feature, but you can check if your theme have this feature or not from customization > woocommerce

and if not then you have to do this by adding [code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17559492/how-can-i-get-product-count-in-each-category-like-woocommerce-back-end)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. As per I know, my theme does have not this feature. That's why I'm looking for an alternate custom way.